# What happens when an int and float variable both having same value is compared using comparison operator?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

What happens when an int and float variable both having same value is compared using comparison operator?

```
 main( )
  {
    int x = 3 ;
    float y = 3.0 ;
    if ( x == y )
      printf ( "\nx and y are equal" ) ;
    else
      printf ( "\nx and y are not equal" ) ;
   }




output : x and y are equal
What happens when x is compared with y variable?
```

Comment: There's an [*implicit conversion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) of at least one value to a common type.

Comment: have you tested that?  You are asking what happens, don't you have a compiler to test it?  That's perfectly legal code, and no undefined behaviour is expected from there (At least with the literal `3.0`)

Answer (score 5):

The `int` is converted *implicitly* to a `float` type; your code is equivalent to

```
if ((float)x == y)
```

Note this happens *even* if the conversion from an `int` to a `float` loses precision (which it doesn't in your case).

Answer (score 2):

A good, general rule is that you should never compare floating-point numbers for exact equality.  Famously, simple-looking code fragments like

```
float f1 = 1.1, f2 = 2.2;
float f3 = 3.3;
if(f1 + f2 == f3) printf("expected\n");
else printf("surprise\n");
```

are quite likely to behave surprisingly.  The reason is that most real numbers (including ordinary decimal fractions like `1.1`) can *not* be represented exactly in a finite-width floating-point representation.

Some numbers can be represented exactly, of course.  In particular, small integers can typically be represented exactly even in low-precision floating-point representations.  So to restate your example, code like

```
int x = 3;
float y = 3.0;
if(x == y) printf("expected\n");
else printf("surprise\n");
```

is virtually guaranteed to print the expected result on any practical computer.

How does it work, exactly?  C supports *mixed-mode arithmetic*.  You're perfectly allowed to write things like `x == y` even if `x` and `y` have different types.  What typically happens is that the compiler inserts implicit conversions to a common type.  So when you write `x == y`, the compiler says to itself.  "Hmm.  I don't have an instruction to compare an int and a float for equality.  But if I convert the int to a float, I'll have two floats, and then I can use the machine's single-precision floating-point equality comparison operator.  So I'll pretend the expression was `(float)x == y`."

But the general rule still stands.  The fact that a floating-point variable can exactly store a small integer like `3.0` (or an exact fraction like `0.5`) does not mean that it can store all integers exactly.  For example, the similar-looking code

```
long int x = 123456789;
float y = 123456789.0;
if(x == (long int)y) printf("expected\n");
else printf("surprise\n");
```

is again quite likely to print a surprising result.